# BufferedReader with InputStreamReader fed with a finished HTTPResponse causes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I have some code that converts my `HTTPResponse` Object into a `JSONObject`, which works fine most of the time:

```
public static JSONObject httpResponseToJson(HttpResponse response) {
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),
                    "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();
            if (json != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                printStatus(jsonObject);
                return jsonObject;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, sometimes it throws a the Android `NetworkOnMainThread exception`. I cannot figure out why, because the response is already finished and there should not be any more network IO involved in that call. For test reasons, if I allow `NetworkOnMainThread`, this method works fine all the time.

Note that all the `HTTPResponse` is fetched with an `AsyncTask` and this is working fine.

I am very interested in any suggestions.

Comment: Where are you running that piece of code? You should post the full `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: In the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs in the main `UI` Thread. Only `doInBackground()` doesn't, so you'll have to move it on here.

Comment: But why? There is no network stuff involved in that call?

Comment: yes there is ... reading from HttpResponse

Comment: OK, do you know why it works 95% of the time then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the response from a `HttpResponse` object also involves a `Network Operation`. Simply process that also in the `doInBackground()` method and modify your `AsyncTask` to pass to the `onPostExecute()` the real result once processed.

Comment: That really solved the problem. Although I am still puzzled why reading the response involves network operation AND why it worked fine 95% of the time... However, thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell because I don't know exactly how your app works, but possibly you have some condition which makes process or not the network operation. But it's always a good idea to separate *any* network operation in the `doInBackground()` method, even if it's not directly related to the operation as such, and process the result in the `onPostExecute()` method to avoid headaches like this.

Answer (score 0):

its mean you are performing some network operation on main thread.The point here is Unless the stream is not closed, you are still performing network operation so move that part into `doInBackGround()` too.

Comment: The input stream does also cause a NetworkOnMainThread exception, even if there is no network stuff done?